# How to keep the auto-increment function (in SQL IDENTITY) for ID after importing from Access to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, auto-increment

I'm importing tables from Access to SQL Server. The column ID in Access is auto-increment, but in SQL Server I must enter every time the ID. It's important to say that there're records in the imported tables and I want to alter the ID be IDENTITY.

I tried to change the ID to IDENTITY, but it's says that I must drop and recreate the tables. Is it possible to alter ID to IDENTITY after importing from Access?

Comment: Have you tried creating the table with an identity column, use [`set identity_insert on`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) while populating it and `set identity_insert off` when complete? Note: you can only have `identity_insert on` for a single table in the database at a time.

Comment: No, you **cannot** add the `IDENTITY` specification in SQL Server to an existing column - just isn't possible. You would need to create a new table with your `ID` column defined as `INT IDENTITY`, then copy over all data with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, and drop the old table. No other way to do this - sorry.

Comment: SSMS should allow one to add or setup a existing column as an identity column. One may have to change the settings in SSMS to allow drop + re-create of tables, but SSMS will do this automatic for you. See my post below, and how I open a existing table in design view, set the column as PK, and then go on to set this existing column as a identify column. This is allowed, and I do this all the time.

Comment: @marc_s - there is another way to do it. If you create an empty table with the same structure (including indexes) that has as the only difference the identity property of one of columns, you can do a partition switch from the table holding the data into the empty one. That changes a size-of-data operation into a metadata-only one. From a scheduling standpoint, it's much more palatable.

Comment: As noted, see my post below. I was free and able to set a existing column to identity, and the only thing I did was use the table designer and set it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in SQL server, you need to set (in most cases) the column that was the PK column as the primery key, and THEN also set the column to be auto increment.

So, open the sql server table in the SSMS designer, and set the ID column as PK.

you also THEN want to set the "identity" settings to auto increment.

so, like this:

In this example, I do BOTH!

I select the ID column, set as PK, and THEN also setup the "autonumbering" system (it works like how auto number in Access does).

[image]

Note that AFTER you do the above, you need to re-link the table(s) from Access.

## Edit: There is some major confusing in regards to this being NOT possible vs that of SSMS having to drop + re-create the table.

SSMS has a setting, and will do all the work for you.

That setting is this and by default one will get a message to this effect:

Tools->Options->Table and Database Designers

[image]

so, if you un-check that box (Prevent saving changes that require table re-creating?

Then you are 100% free from the table designer to turn on, or set, or un-set the identify column.

Obviously, the above screen cap gif shows me doing this task without a problem. Such operations does keep existing data. So, behind the scenes, yes, SQL server is dropping the table, re-creating the table, and moving the data for you. It is a operation with "some" risk, but I done this for years without a issue.

So, if one un-checks that box above, then one is rather free to add the identity column to the database in question.